# QML animations visible property changes

Tags: qt, animation, qt4, transition, qml

I want an animation to be painted when an element becomes visible (is should appear smoothly, not the whole at all)

I tried this

```
states: State
{
    name: "iconOff"
    when: iconOnSwitch.checked == false
    PropertyChanges { target: selectIconRow; visible: false }
}

transitions: Transition
{
    reversible: true
    from: ""
    to: "iconOff"
    PropertyAnimation
    {
        properties: "x,y,visible"
        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
        from: selectIconRow
        property: "visible"
    }
}
```

But the selectIconRow still appears immediately

How can I use such an animation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because it's boolean, `visible` property cannot be animated. Perhaps `opacity` could do the trick.

Comment: Care with opacity.
If something is fully transparent with opacity=0.0 its different from visible=false.
For example a nested MouseArea in your not visible item is still clickable.

Comment: That's true. Generally there are two approaches. For simple cases `visible` could be binded to `opacity != 0`. In more complex scenarios state change with transition is the way to go.

Answer (score 13):

Here is how to do it with `opacity`:

```
Rectangle {
    id: myRect
    property bool stateVisible: true
    ...
    states: [
        State { when: stateVisible;
            PropertyChanges {   target: myRect; opacity: 1.0    }
        },
        State { when: !stateVisible;
            PropertyChanges {   target: myRect; opacity: 0.0    }
        }
    ]
    transitions: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; duration: 500}
    }
}
```

Keep in mind the advice of Vasco Rinaldo.

Comment: This didn't quite work on my system, see my answer with minor corrections. Thanks for this snippet anyway though.

Answer (score 9):

Just for future references, here's my solution which takes care also of Vasco's warning. Basically I'm animating the `visible` property of the component after the opacity has changed. It hurts seeing a `NumberAnimation` on a boolean, but it's working:

```
states: [
    State{
        name: "Visible"
        PropertyChanges{target: root; opacity: 1.0}
        PropertyChanges{target: root; visible: true}
    },
    State{
        name:"Invisible"
        PropertyChanges{target: root; opacity: 0.0}
        PropertyChanges{target: root; visible: false}
    }
]

transitions: [
        Transition {
            from: "Visible"
            to: "Invisible"

            SequentialAnimation{
               NumberAnimation {
                   target: root
                   property: "opacity"
                   duration: 500
                   easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
               }
               NumberAnimation {
                   target: root
                   property: "visible"
                   duration: 0
               }
            }
        },
        Transition {
            from: "Invisible"
            to: "Visible"
            SequentialAnimation{
               NumberAnimation {
                   target: root
                   property: "visible"
                   duration: 0
               }
               NumberAnimation {
                   target: root
                   property: "opacity"
                   duration: 500
                   easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
               }
            }
        }
    ]
```

This introduces also a transition when the component is vanishing.

Comment: If it hurts too much you can use a "PropertyAnimation" instead.

Comment: or a "PropertyAction"

Answer (score 5):

I had to modify Uga Buga's answer slightly to make it work, here's what I got:

```
Rectangle {
    id: myRect
    property bool stateVisible: true
            ...
    states: [
        State { when: myRect.stateVisible; 
                PropertyChanges {   target: myRect; opacity: 1.0    }},
        State { when: !myRect.stateVisible;
                PropertyChanges {   target: myRect; opacity: 0.0    }}
    ]
    transitions: [ Transition { NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; duration: 500}} ]
}
```

Please note that stateVisible is referenced through item id, it doesn't work without it on my system. Maybe some change in API caused this.

I also added square bracket in `transitions` field as an array is required there (although QML syntax seems to allow spelling without brackets)

Answer (score 3):

```
Item {

 scale: visible ? 1.0 : 0.1
 Behavior on scale { 
   NumberAnimation  { duration: 500 ; easing.type: Easing.InOutBounce  } 
  }

}
```

does the trick for me.

Comment: This doesn't animate when hiding the Item.

Answer (score 1):

`visibility`   can be used in `NumberAnimation`, but to get the needed fading result, `opacity` animation could be used; like turning visibility ON from function like the following example:

```
Rectangle{
    id:fadingRect
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible: false
    opacity: 0.00
    color: "red"
    Component.onCompleted: {
        animRect.start()
    }
}
SequentialAnimation{
    id:animRect
    NumberAnimation { target: fadingRect; property: "visible"; from: 0; to:1; duration: 20}
    NumberAnimation { target: fadingRect; property: "opacity"; from: 0.00; to:1.00; duration: 4000 }

    onStopped: console.log(fadingRect.visible)
}
```

Or :

```
Rectangle{
    id:fadingRect
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible: false
    opacity: 1
    color: "red"
    Component.onCompleted: {
        animRect.start()
    }
        NumberAnimation { id:animRect; target: fadingRect; property: "opacity"; from: 0; to:1; duration: 2000;
        onStarted: { fadingRect.visible=true; console.log(fadingRect.visible)}
        }
}
```