# Problem applying animation to InputPanel QML type

Tags: qt, animation, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have the following input panel :

```
        InputPanel{
                id: inputPanel
                visible: false
                y : window.height/2
                width: window.width
                height: window.height/2
                transitions: Transition {

                    NumberAnimation {
                        target: inputPanel
                        property: "height"
                        duration: 500
                        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                    }

                }
            }
```

But that [NumberAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-numberanimation.html) has no effect, so are [SmoothedAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-smoothedanimation.html) , [PathAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-pathanimation.html) and [SequentialAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-sequentialanimation.html).
I use Qt 5.14

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `InputPanel`, it says you should not try to set the height as that is automatically calculated to maintain the aspect ratio. Don't you really want to animate it's x/y position instead?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I also tried using x/y property .But still no animation.Also if I don't manipulate the width and height directly , it would either cover the other elements in my form or expands to an undesirable size.

Comment: `Transition` only makes sense when used with `State`s, or rather it will trigger on a state change so your code will never run the animation.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi "The keyboard size is automatically calculated from the available width; that is, the keyboard maintains the aspect ratio specified by the current style. Therefore the application should only set the width and y coordinates of the InputPanel, and not the height."
In other words, if you set the width the size of the thing is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You want a [behaviour](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html).

```
InputPanel {
    Behavior on width {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 2000
        }
    }
    width: 400
    active: true
}
```

As mentioned by folibis, transitions are for state changes.

Comment: Still after using "Behavior" I cannot see any animation.

Comment: Try animating `width` instead of `height`. See my updated (tested) example

Comment: Nothing yet. Which Qt version do you use?

Comment: I'm using 5.12.7. Have you tried my stripped down example?

Comment: Yes.But it didn't work. At least in Qt 5.14. Sorry I haven't 5.12 to test that.

Comment: I used your code exactly as you posted it besides the "id" and "visible : false" property. The latter is to enable the program to show it via a click on some button to better demonstrate the animation.

Comment: Could you please post the code that doesn't work after using Behavior on width?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Changing `visible` does not change `width` or `height`. Do you want to animate changes in `visible` ?

Comment: @TimonvanderBerg Using "visible" as the animation property only causes some delay in showing the keyboard(e.g it appears after 300 ms). But it cannot animate it.

Comment: @Skonitsa I copy-pasted the code in the answer plus the "id" and "visible" property. Nothing more.Nothing less. Furthermore if the target of your comment is someone but the owner of the post which you're commenting on , please add "@target_username" at the beginning of the comment to notify him/her .

Comment: @ParsaMousavi if you want changes in `visible` to be accompanied by animations you should have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333112/qml-animations-visible-property-changes

Comment: @TimonvanderBerg That works .Nice . Instead of assigning the "stateVisible" to true in that example , I assigned it to "inputPanel.visible" so that if the visibility of the panel changes , the animation triggers. It generates a clean fade effect . Although I wanted the animation to be on the height property , but that's nice.You can post it as the answer or edit your current one. Thanks a lot.